# Can three dots be used for context menu?

Tags: menu, accessibility

[image: I am used three dots for context menu]

Does three dots in linear make sense "more" in web applications, i have seen them only in mobile design?

Comment: Implement it and test with your users.

Comment: I think a 'gear' icon would fit this design better. It definitely corresponds to your context menu options.

Comment: Down arrow is best. Ellipsis is used a lot in Windows to indicate a modal popup, which this menu isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the user would not know what ... means. Try this

[image]

Comment: The down-pointing triangle is also used for "Expand" command.

Comment: What makes you say that most people won't recognise them? That's a bit of an assumption.

Comment: I had used this for my company app and it was tested in my office in San Francisco. 73% people did not know what it was. 45 % thought something is loading. 6 % actually clicked on it . 28% people were trying to swipe the button.( they though 3 dots represent number of screens like android )

Answer (score 1):

*They almost make as much sense as the word "more" ...*

As with any icon, I personally have taken to do what you're doing everywhere else in that design: use an icon with a word next to it.

"More ..."

Or "Menu" followed by the hamburger icon.

Alternatively, use a down arrow. That one has worked for years, and is still seeing heavy use across (web based) applications.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a small drop-down arrow here? This icon is ok, but seems that some dialog box/window will be opened by clicking this.
Yes you are right, this icon is used to display More options.

Comment: The down-pointing triangle is also used for "Expand" command.

Answer (score 0):

Dots, in this form, are communicative of either loading, or progression. As suggested above, a drop arrow would work well. Perhaps, consider an angled arrow as this also hints at the path new content will appear in.